# How to find array[x] = array[x] + 1

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, factorial

This is my code to find facotrial of a number and to find number of occurunces of all digits in the factorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int iFactorial(int iCount)
{
    int iProduct = 1;
    int iNumber = 1;
    while (iNumber <= iCount)
    {
        iProduct *= iNumber;
        iNumber++;
    }
    return iProduct;
}

int main(void)
{
    int iFac[10] = {0};
    int iCount = 0;
    printf("Please input a Integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&iCount);
    iFac[iCount] = iFactorial(iCount);
    printf("\nThe value of the factorial of %d is %d\n",iCount, iFac[iCount]);
    int i;
    int dig[10] = {0};
    while (iFac <=0)
    {
        int n;
        n= ((iFac % 10) + 1);
        dig[n] = dig[n] +1;
        iFac = iFac / 10;
    }

    for (i = 0; i > 9; i++)
    {
        if (dig[i+1] >0)
        {
            printf ("%d     %d\n", i, dig[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to find the proper method for writing `array[x] = array[x] + 1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can highlight a whole code block and press ctl-k to format it as a continuous code block.

Comment: `while (iFac <=0)` <- `iFac` is an array. Did you mean `iFac[iCount]`? (And what's with the variable names, C wasn't developed by Apple.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I bet the `i` there stands for `int`.  /2cents

Comment: @DanielFischer A long time ago, in systems that had type checking which didn't type check too well (or were overly aggressive in type promotion), people would prefix a character as a "notation" to indicate what type the variable was, so `iFact` is an "integer Fact", and so on.  It was called "Hungarian notation", and it sometimes makes a resurgence, even though type-checking compilers make it _entirely irrelevant_ in the modern world.

Comment: @DanielFischer Also even if corrected the loop seems like an infinite loop to me. A factorial number can never be <=0.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Nit: that form is called *Systems* Hungarian, [not to be confused](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) with *Apps* Hungarian. (Although usually, excluding a few standard rules, I think it's just better to write out the "full name".)

Comment: @EdwinBuck Although that wasn't what Simonyi meant. (I was just attempting to be funny with the Apple jibe.)

Comment: @Aposperite That's right, the condition should be `> 0`. However, if `int` is 32 bits, `iFactorial` will overflow for inputs `> 12`, so the value in the array could indeed be negative.

Comment: @pst Type hierarchies makes _Apps Hungarian_ a dead art.  `objectUser`, `nameableUser`, or `userUser` since they all are the same "type" in a hierarchy.  _System Hungarian_ still lives, but it really shouldn't.  It makes changing a datatype a lesson in how to rename a variable (blech!)

Answer (score 1):

I think following code will clear how you wanted to count the digits.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial (int n)
{
 if ( n == 1 ) return 1 ; 
 return n * factorial( n-1 ) ;
}

int main()
{

//Input number
int num ;
scanf( "%d", &num ) ;  

//Calculate Factorial
int fact = factorial ( num ) ;
cout<< "\nFactorial of Number is " << fact ;

//Count the frequency of Digits
int dig[10] = {0} ;

while( fact )
{
 int i = fact % 10 ;
 dig[i]++ ;
 fact /= 10 ;  
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
   printf("\n The digit %d is present %d times " , i , dig[i] );

return 0 ;
}
```

Make sure you dont input large values for calculating the factorial for a number.